# Trying to make it where you can select books from a list and then gives an itemized receipt at the end using python

Tags: python

Using python I am trying to make it where the books in a text file display and the user can select a book and a quantity and do this in a loop. As they do this it is supposed to save it to a text file as a receipt and print it out when the user is done making their selections. This is what I've been able to accomplish so far.

```
cusName = input("What is your name?")

def main():
    def menu():
       print("Here is a list of items that we have:")

books_file= open("Books.txt","r")
lines = books_file.readlines()

aryBooks = []

for line in lines:
    print(line)

bookChoice = input("Which book would you like?")

bookQty = input("You chose",  bookChoice , "How many would you like?")

print ("Qty:", bookQty)
print ("Item:", bookChoice)

price = print ("Price:", book[2])
print ("SubTotal:", price * bookQty)

repeat = input("Would you like another item? Y or N")

 receipt_file= open("receipt.txt","w")
 lines = receipt_file.writelines()


for i in range(0,len(aryBooks)):
    print(i + 1, aryBooks[i])
```

Comment: Beware, in Python indentation is the only way to delimit blocks. As your indentation is wrong (2 consecutive `def` lines at same level), it is hard to guess what your program actually is.

Comment: Ya those will probably come out. Im just trying to get the base code down to make all this work

Comment: If you want to show that main is effectively empty use `def main(): pass`

Comment: A few things to note: 1- you can remove the + in every print, 2- what are you trying to do with this line? `price = print ("Price:", +book[2])` and 3- careful you opened a file at the end of the program but never closed it.

Comment: @js0415 Again, please [format your code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks). Indentation is _really important_ in Python.

Comment: the price = print ("Price:", +book[2]) is supposed to display the price of the book, which in the text file is number 2 in the array. How can I edit my original question on here? Thanks!

Comment: Nevermind found the edit!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the code below:

```
def menu():
    # Main loop for shopping
    cart = {}

    # Read books here
    books = read_books()

    while True:
        # Loop until user does not want to shop any longer
        print("Here is a list of items that we have:\n")

        for book_num, (book_name, book_price) in books.items():
            print(f'#{book_num}: {book_name} -- ${book_price}')

        bookChoice = input("Which book would you like? (Please enter a number)\n")

        # Make sure user enters the right number
        try:
            price = books[bookChoice][1]
        except:
            print('Sorry you chose the wrong number')
            print()
            continue

        bookQty = int(input(f"You chose {books[bookChoice][0]}. How many would you like?\n"))

        subtotal = price * bookQty
        cart[books[bookChoice][0]] = (bookQty, subtotal)

        print (f"Qty: {bookQty}")
        print (f"Item: {books[bookChoice][0]}")
        print (f"Price: {price}")
        print (f"SubTotal: {subtotal}")

        repeat = input("Would you like another item? Y or N\n")

        # End loop if answer was No
        if repeat.lower() == 'n' or repeat.lower == "no":
            print(f'Your total was: {sum([y for x, y in cart.values()])}')
            generate_receipt('receipt.txt', books, cart)
            print('Have a good day!\n')
            break
        else:
            print('Here is what you have thus far:')
            for name, (qty, sub) in cart.items():
                print(f'Name: {name} ; Qty: {qty} ; Subtotal: {sub}')
            print()

def generate_receipt(path_to_receipt, books, cart):
    # Generate receipt based on shopping cart
    with open(path_to_receipt, 'a') as receipt_file:
        for name, (qty, subtotal) in cart.items():
            receipt_file.write(f'Qty: {qty} ; Item: {name}; Total: {sum([y for x, y in cart.values()])}; Subtotal: {subtotal}\n')

def main():
    # Main loop that starts the shopping
    cusName = input("What is your name?\n")

    print(f'Hi {cusName}. Welcome to the bookstore!')
    menu()

def read_books(path_to_books="Books.txt"):
    # Read in the books from the file
    with open(path_to_books, 'r') as f:
        books = f.readlines()
        books = [book.strip().split(',') for book in books]
        books = {book_num: (book_name, int(book_price)) for book_num, book_name, book_price in books}

    return books

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The output file might not be what you want but that can be fixed really easily.

My `Books.txt` is as follows:

```
 15,Harry Potter,20
 2,LOTR,25
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185087/discussion-on-answer-by-hqkhan-trying-to-make-it-where-you-can-select-books-from).